# Is there any difference between a 'slideshow' and a 'carousel'?

Tags: photo-gallery

Are Web "slideshows" and "carousels" the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

For "Web slideshow" or "carousel", I mean HTML image galleries like:

- [Flexslider by WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)
- [Nivo Slider™](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider)
- [Juicebox](http://www.juicebox.net)

Comment: You showed examples of what you consider slideshows. Why don't you show what you consider a carousel?

Comment: ok I have edited the question

Comment: Original question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/180612/26651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are somewhat similar:

- Show pieces of content one at a time
- Controls for forward and backwards
- Autoplay feature that can be configured to transition automatically on a timer

However, I would draw the following distinctions:

#### Slideshow

- Primarily for viewing a set of images one at a time.
- May support a very large number of images.
- Preloads the next image for instantaneous display.
- Typically uses common image transitions such as fade and wipe.
- Usually uses buttons or thumbnails for previous and next.

[image] ([image source](http://www.santosh143.com/search/label/Slideshow))

#### Carousel

- For viewing a set of content blocks (usually more than just images) one at a time.
- Usually supports a small number of elements (up to six or so) because it features a visible button to navigate to each of them.
- Typically uses sliding transitions rather than fading transitions.
- Often shows some of the actual content  of the previous and next blocks (with a portion faded or angled) rather than relying on buttons alone.

[image] ([image source](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/carousel-02-dynamic.html))

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a semantics issue.  I would say that carousel is likely a more developer oriented term while web slide show is a more user friend show.  I doubt you have non-developers as for a web carousel on their sites.